# RF - changing a trace slightly from original design...?

Tags: rf, pcb-design

I am trying to make a new PCB for my self just for experimenting.

I found a document on TI website that suggests using a single chip [50Ohm Balun](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra380a/swra380a.pdf)

That is fantastic as it saves anybody faffing about with calibrations and all that..

I have made a PCB before using a symmetrical PCB antenna with no balun and it worked fine in close range. TI always uses the Inverted F antenna as they say it performs the best..

I want to extend the range but i want to keep the PCB as compact as possible.
I found this [SMD 2.4 Antenna](http://rhu004.sma-promail.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987650-5702.pdf)

and I just wondered if i can connect it directly to the Balun?

The catch is that i need to change TI's recommend trace, add a 90degree bend to it.. otherwise the footprint is the same.

The original HOT wire is greyed out.. and all i want to do is put a kink into it.

[image]

I know RF is very temperamental to the slightest design change and I have no spectrum analysers or even experience to detect what this change could cause in the signal.

Can I .. just do this?

**EDIT**
I re read the pdf a few hundred times and realised it says *this monopole antenna requires simple stripline matching on the PCB without the need for discrete components.*

So am I correct in assuming that it is fine to put the bend in the place that I want?I do not really understand what that means.

**EDIT 2**

Do you think if i place it at 45 degrees.. it should be ok as its omnidirectional..

[image]

**EDIT 3**

THe mos logical way, as commented would be shifting it over. I think I will go with this..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My one concern was that the length of the transmission line from the chip to the antenna might be chosen to be some particular fraction of a wavelength for matching purposes. But the antenna datasheet shows high return loss at the operating frequency, indicating it simply appears as a 50 Ohm load at 2.4 GHz.

Given that, either of your designs is likely to work. The initial design (90-degree bend) could be improved by leaving the antenna pad at a 45 degree angle to the "southwest" and then making another 45-degree bend when it meets up with the existing track.

The second design (part placed at 45 degrees) should also be fine, but might be harder to work with if you were doing a very space-constrained design.

Another option would be to keep the antenna oriented at 90 degrees but move it to the right or left a few mm so that a straight track from IC would run straight to the appropriate pin.

Comment: Well at the moment I cant argue with that.. and it was my original thought.. so I will give it a go.. The spec does not warn about anything, and the guideline is pretty simple.. just add it to the trace... so I will leave the trace as it is an position the antenna foot ontop of the conenctor.

Comment: BTW, my answer assumed you know how to specify your board to get the correct characteristic impedance in the antenna feed trace. If not, you'll want to read up on that topic before you finalize your design. For example you'll want to use the exact same layer thicknesses and laminate material (not just FR-4 but same manufacturer and product) as TI did, otherwise you'll need to recalculate the trace width.

Comment: When you say layer thickness do you mean the PCB thickness or the actual copper thickness of the trace? I did not even realise that could pose a problem.. RF is quite a pain..

Comment: The PCB thickness is most important. Its not clear if this is a 2-layer or a multilayer board - the critical dimension is the height of the track above the ground plane. The copper thickness (including any plated-on metal from through-hole plating) also has a small effect, but it's not as critical.

Comment: Thanks-- Really, thank you for your comments- You really answered a few questions and deserve the credit. I am sure you are a valued member of your workplace.